# What are the next() middlewares/routes relative to app.use(express.static(...))?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I can serve static assets (which I created by `npm run build`ing React source code) like this:

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'apps', 'home', 'build')))
```

If I want to protect a URL and its static assets, I can do this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
  else {
    app.use('/profile', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'apps', 'profile', 'build')))
    next();
  }
});
```

If I don't call `next()` there, the program hangs when I make an authenticated attempt at `/profile`.

Which middleware/routes are being called next? Without authentication, `app.use(express.static(...))` seems to have no problem serving static assets without `next()`. Why do I need it now? I don't have GET routes defined for `/profile` or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attaching middleware dynamically in response to requests is not correct. (An authenticated request will make all future requests work unauthenticated with that code.) Instead, you should put authorization-checking middleware ahead of your file-serving middleware to allow it to intercept requests.

```js
const requireAuthentication = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.redirect('/login');
  } else {
    next();
  }
};

app.use('/profile',
  requireAuthentication,
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'apps', 'profile', 'build')));
```

Comment: So separate the authentication middleware, and then next() means proceed from requireAuthentication to express.static(), right?

Comment: @sammy: Right. :)

Comment: Ok so in my original example, next() was relative to the outer app.use which confirmed authentication, and the next thing to do was to serve those static assets at the /profile route as defined in the inner app.use. But like you say, this is a problematic spaghetti way to do it. Thanks I'll accept your answer.